# how can I get the ARM MULL instruction to produce its output in a uint64_t in gcc?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, 32bit-64bit

I would like to introduce some assembly code into a c99 codebase. I want to use the UMULL instruction from the ARM CPU to multiply 2 uint32_t and get the result immediately into a uint64_t.

Now a uint64_t needs 2 registers, so how do I specify the output and the constraints of the asm block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!

The following code outputs what you want using `GCC -O` or higher without resorting to assembler:

```
uint32_t a, b;
uint64_t c;
...
c = (uint64_t)a * (uint64_t)b;
```

or if you feel you must use machine-specific asm, you can go:

```
uint32_t a, b;
uint64_t c;
```

asm ("umull %Q0, %R0, %1, %2" : "=r"(c) : "r"(a), "r"(b));

`c`'s register name is the first of the register pair, and %Q and %R pick out the lower and upper 32-bit registers of the pair. See gcc/config/arm/arm.md -> umulsidi3 for an example.

However, if you can stay in C, that gives the optimizer a chance to do more and is kinder on readers of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Indeed the C version does what I want it to do, very cool.
And many thanks for the %Q and %R syntax, that's what I was looking for in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The `umull` instruction produces its results into two 32-bit registers. I suggest explicitly reassembling the 64-bit value with something like that:

```
/* assuming the 64-bit result was stored in "hi" (upper
   half) and "lo" (lower half) */
uint64_t v = ((uint64_t)hi << 32) | (uint64_t)lo;
```

The compiler optimizer should notice that the left-shift is pure data routing, and the resulting code should be fine. To be sure, just use `-S` to check the compiler output.