# how to do 32*32 bit multiplication in cortex m3

Tags: assembly, arm, embedded

I'm doing 32 bit multiplication for cortex m3 controller using "umull" arm instruction. I'm getting result in two 32 bit registers RdLo, RdHi. how to get the complete 64 bit result.

i wrote a function which takes two 32 bit values and i multiplied them using "umull" instruction which gives result in RdLo, RdHi two 32 bit registers.

i want to return a 64 bit result from that function.

```
long mulhi1, mullo1;
unsigned long Multiply(long i,long j)
{
  asm ("umull  %0, %1, %[input_i], %[input_j];"
  : "=r" (mullo1), "=r" (mulhi1)
  : [input_i] "r" (i), [input_j] "r" (j)
      : /* No clobbers */
  );
}
```

I'm expecting 64 bit result as return value from that function. But "umull" gives result in mullo1,mulhi1 seperate 32 bit registers.
please help me what changes has to make to get 64 bit result.

Comment: Have you tried `unsigned long long Multiply(long i, long j) { return (unsigned long long)i * j; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1:

**Use a union of 32 and 64 bit integers to receive the result**

```
#include <stdint.h>

union dw {
    uint64_t dword;
    struct {
#ifdef __ARMEB__
        uint32_t high_word;
        uint32_t low_word;
#else
        uint32_t low_word;
        uint32_t high_word;
#endif
    };
};

uint64_t umull(uint32_t op1, uint32_t op2) {
    union dw result;
    asm volatile(
        "umull %[result_low], %[result_high], %[operand_1], %[operand_2]"
        :[result_low] "=r" (result.low_word), [result_high] "=r" (result.high_word)
        :[operand_1] "r" (op1), [operand_2] "r" (op2)
    );
    return result.dword;
}
```

Also note that `unsigned long` is a 32-bit type on Cortex-M3, you need `unsigned long long`, or use the predefined type from `<stdint.h>`.

---

Method 2:

**Use `%Q` und `%R` in the assembly block to form the 64-bit result.**

(Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193542/how-can-i-get-the-arm-mull-instruction-to-produce-its-output-in-a-uint64-t-in-gc/2193866#2193866), which might be a duplicate by the way)

```
uint64_t umull(uint32_t op1, uint32_t op2) {
    uint64_t result;
    asm volatile(
        "umull %Q[dwresult], %R[dwresult], %[operand_1], %[operand_2]"
        :[dwresult] "=r" (result)
        :[operand_1] "r" (op1), [operand_2] "r" (op2)
    );
    return result;
}
```

This is not exactly well documented, one has to browse the gcc sources to find it.

Answer (score 4):

You could just let the compiler do it:

```
unsigned long long mul64 ( unsigned int a, unsigned int b )
{
    return(((unsigned long long)a)*((unsigned long long)b));
}

00000000 <mul64>:
   0:   fba0 0101   umull   r0, r1, r0, r1
   4:   4770        bx  lr
```

or you could use real assembly language:

```
.thumb
.cpu cortex-m3
mul64:
    umull r0,r1,r0,r1
    bx  lr
```

Comment: note: you need to either use stdint.h or know the native sizes for a specific compiler, for gnu unsigned long for arm is 32 bits as well as unsigned int.  unsigned long long is 64 bit.

Answer (score -2):

since cortex M3 is a 32 bit architecture you can't return (in a register) a 64 bit result. 
I think the better way to do this is to reserve 64 bit in your data segment and store here the result as a 2 contigous registers, then return the address of this.

Another method would be using stack, by pushing both result registers.

Comment: The ARM EABI calling convention actually describes that a 64 bit result is returned in the registers r0 and r1.

Comment: The code in the question *is* trying to return them in static variables (which is horrible).  If you were going to return in memory, the sane way would be for the caller to pass an output pointer.  Anyway, the compiler takes care of the calling convention for you!  The OP just wants output from a GNU C inline asm statement.